# Java program to get the current date without timestamp

Tags: java

I need a Java program to get the **current date without a timestamp**:

```
Date d = new Date();
```

gives me date and timestamp.

But I need only the date, without a timestamp. I use this date to compare with another date object that does not have a timestamp.

On printing

```
System.out.println("Current Date : " + d)
```

of d it should print `May 11 2010  - 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` object *is* a kind of timestamp - it contains a number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. So you can't use a standard `Date` object to contain just a day / month / year, without a time.

As far as I know, there's no really easy way to compare dates by only taking the date (and not the time) into account in the standard Java API. You can use class `Calendar` and clear the hour, minutes, seconds and milliseconds:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
cal.clear(Calendar.AM_PM);
cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Do the same with another `Calendar` object that contains the date that you want to compare it to, and use the `after()` or `before()` methods to do the comparison.

As explained into the Javadoc of **java.util.Calendar.clear(int field)**:

> The **HOUR_OF_DAY**, **HOUR** and **AM_PM** fields are handled independently and the the resolution rule for the time of day is applied. Clearing one of the fields doesn't reset the hour of day value of this Calendar. Use set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0) to reset the hour value.

*edit* - The answer above is from 2010; in Java 8, there is a new date and time API in the package `java.time` which is much more powerful and useful than the old `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes. Use the new date and time classes instead of the old ones.

Comment: I didn't know about cal.clear(), I'm going to steal it and update my answer.

Comment: You may if you give me +1 ;-)

Comment: This works, but you have to clear both HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY to get a true clearing - i.e., setting of the time to 12am.

Comment: @WhyGeeEx (years after your comment, which may have been true then):  Docs as of Java 7 clarify this as not necessary: If HOUR_OF_DAY is the most recent field set, then it takes precedence over "AM_PM + HOUR". http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#time_resolution  "If there is any conflict in calendar field values, Calendar gives priorities to calendar fields that have been set more recently". Then it goes on to specifically show HOUR_OF_DAY vs "AM_PM + HOUR".

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Yep, 2010 was very pre-Java-7.

Answer (score 11):

You could always use [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)' `DateUtils` class. It has the static method `isSameDay()` which "Checks if two date objects are on the same day ignoring time."

```
static boolean isSameDay(Date date1, Date date2)
```

Comment: I read the documentation of isSameDay, and I don't get how it works. How can it determine the day without using the time zone? sometimes two Date instances can be either on the same day or on different days (before and after midnight) depending on the time zone being assumed. Does it assume the default timezone of the system?

Comment: I don't know exactly what it does. You'd have to look at the source to be sure. However, if you look at the Date API, it appears to do everything based on the local time zone. In fact, all of its methods relating to converting to other timezones are deprecated. So, really Date looks like it doesn't really deal with timezones. If you want to do anything with timezones, look at Calendar.

Comment: Date internally is milliseconds since "January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT". I would expect day computations to also be in GMT.

Comment: On the other hand, I see that `(new Date).toString()` uses the default locale of current device (on Android anyway) to determine time zone. So `isSameDay` might do the same.

Answer (score 8):

Use **DateFormat** to solve this problem:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
print(dateFormat.format(new Date()); // will print like 2014-02-20
print(dateFormat2.format(new Date()); // will print like 02-20-2014
```

Comment: This is a simple way of getting the date in a format you want.

Answer (score 6):

I did as follows and it worked: (Current date without timestamp)

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date today = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: it gives timestamp also with date

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
// Format a string containing a date.
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import static java.util.Calendar.*;

Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
String s = String.format("Duke's Birthday: %1$tm %1$te,%1$tY", c);
// -> s == "Duke's Birthday: May 23, 1995"
```

Have a look at the [`Formatter` API documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: I will not pass any date as u mentioned.

Comment: Updated the code to go through GregorianCalendar.getInstance() which returns current date.

Comment: Why use `GregorianCalendar` explicitly - why not just use `Calendar.getInstance()`?

Answer (score 4):

```
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy");
  java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
  System.out.println("Current Date : " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get by this date:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
print(dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted answer by Jesper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806403/642706) is correct but now outdated. The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

## java.time

Instead use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework, built into Java 8 and later, [back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [further adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.png]

If you truly do not care about time-of-day and time zones, use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) in the java.time framework ().

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2014 , 5 , 6 );
```

### Today

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, make your intention clear by calling `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

### Moment

If you care about specific moments, specific points on the timeline, do not use `LocalDate`. If you care about the date as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region, do not use `LocalDate`.

Be aware that if you have *any* chance of needing to deal with other time zones or UTC, this is the wrong way to go. Naïve programmers tend to think they do not need time zones when in fact they do.

### Strings

Call `toString` to generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = localDate.toString();
```

> 2014-05-06

For other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` class.

## Joda-Time

Though now supplanted by java.time, you can use the similar [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class in the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library (the inspiration for java.time).

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( 2014, 5, 6 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use apache commons lib [`DateUtils.truncate()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#truncate(java.util.Calendar,%20int)):

```
Date now = new Date();
Date truncated = DateUtils.truncate(now, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Time will be set to `00:00:00` so you can work with this date or print it formatted:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

System.out.println(dateFormat.format(now);        // 2010-05-11 11:32:47
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(truncated);  // 2010-05-11 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); 
    private static Date NOW = new Date();
    static {
        try {
            NOW = df1.parse(df1.format(new Date()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a Date instead for a Calendar for comparison, this is the shortest piece of code you could use:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Date d = new GregorianCalendar(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                               c.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                               c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).getTime();
```

This way you make sure the hours/minute/second/millisecond values are blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.  Use Calendar to manipulate time fields (reset them to zero), then get the Date from the Calendar.

```
Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
c.clear( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY );
c.clear( Calendar.MINUTE );
c.clear( Calendar.SECOND );
c.clear( Calendar.MILLISECOND );
Date today = c.getTime();
```

Or do the opposite.  Put the date you want to compare to in a calendar and compare calendar dates

```
Date compareToDate;  // assume this is set before going in.
Calendar today = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
Calendar compareTo = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
compareTo.setTime( compareToDate );
if( today.get( Calendar.YEAR ) == compareTo.get( Calendar.YEAR ) &&
    today.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR  ) == compareTo.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR  ) ) {
  // They are the same day!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an inelegant way of doing it quick without additional dependencies.
You could just use java.sql.Date, which extends java.util.Date although for comparisons you will have to compare the Strings.

```
java.sql.Date dt1 = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String dt1Text = dt1.toString();
System.out.println("Current Date1 : " + dt1Text);

Thread.sleep(2000);

java.sql.Date dt2 = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String dt2Text = dt2.toString();
System.out.println("Current Date2 : " + dt2Text);

boolean dateResult = dt1.equals(dt2);
System.out.println("Date comparison is " + dateResult);
boolean stringResult = dt1Text.equals(dt2Text);
System.out.println("String comparison is " + stringResult);
```

Output:

> Current Date1 : 2010-05-10
>   Current Date2 : 2010-05-10
>   Date comparison is false
>   String comparison is true

Answer (score 0):

I did as follows and it worked:

```
calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 0);
calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date date1 = calendar1.getTime();       // Convert it to date
```

Do this for other instances to which you want to compare. This logic worked for me; I had to compare the dates whether they are equal or not, but you can do different comparisons (before, after, equals, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution and the following worked for me.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
    calendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    calendar.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    calendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

    Date today = calendar.getTime();
```

Please note that I am using calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0) for HOUR_OF_DAY instead of using the clear method, because it is suggested in Calendar.clear method's javadocs as the following

> The HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR and AM_PM fields are handled independently and
>   the the resolution rule for the time of day is applied. Clearing one
>   of the fields doesn't reset the hour of day value of this Calendar.
>   Use set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0) to reset the hour value.

With the above posted solution I get output as

```
Wed Sep 11 00:00:00 EDT 2013
```

Using clear method for HOUR_OF_DAY resets hour at 12 when executing after 12PM or 00 when executing before 12PM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for get only date:

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat dm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
System.out.println("current date is :    " + dm.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is full Example of it.But you have to cast Sting back to Date.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

//TODO OutPut should LIKE in this format MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
public class TestDateExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat changeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
         Date thisDate = new Date();//changeFormat.parse("10 07 2012"); 
         System.out.println("Current Date : " + thisDate);
         changeFormat.format(thisDate); 
        System.out.println("----------------------------"); 
        System.out.println("After applying formating :");
        String strDateOutput = changeFormat.format(thisDate);
        System.out.println(strDateOutput);

    }

}
```

[image: Eaxmple]