# Convert dateTime to date in dd/MM/yy format in java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a JODA `DateTime` `2012-12-31T13:32:56.483+13:00`. I would like to convert it to Date in `dd/MM/yy` format. So I'm expecting code to return Date like - 31/12/12.

Code -

```
    // Input dateTime = 2012-12-31T13:32:56.483+13:00
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateTime.toString("dd/MM/yy"));
```

Results:

```
Output - Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 NZDT 2012
Expected Output - 31/12/12
```

When I do the following, I get the expected output but I don't know how to convert it to Date-

```
String string = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

Please help me.

Thx

EDIT -  I want my end result to be Util Date in dd/MM/yy format. I Do not want String output. My input is Joda DateTime yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:+GMT. I need to convert JodaDateTime to UtilDate.

Comment: Ya. I don't like it too but db allows only 2 digit year in my schema. Also, I get the same error for 4 digit year.

Comment: Date doesn't inherently have a format. Date can be formatted to/ or parsed from a String via a specified DateFormat, but it doesn't inherently hold or have a format.

Comment: I am trying to convert JodaTime -> java.util.Date and truncate the time component and get the resulting date in dd/MM/yy format. Thanks

Comment: Great!  I'll edit my answer below. Thanks Sara.

Comment: Probably this is what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050170/java-getting-date-without-time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I said originally, Date objects do not have an inherent format. `java.util.Date` holds a millisecond time value, representing both date & time. Dates are parsed from string, or formatted to string, via your choice of DateFormat.

The strings may be formatted per specification, but the Date objects behind them are always full precision & do not have any inherent notion of format.

---

To truncate a combined "date and time" `java.util.Date` to just the date component, leaving it effectively at midnight:

```
public static Date truncateTime (Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime( date);
    cal.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

If you're coming from JodaTime `DateTime`, you can do this more easily working mostly in the JodaTime API.

```
public static Date truncateJodaDT (DateTime dt) {
    java.util.Date result = dt.toDateMidnight().toDate();
    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps!

See:

- http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toDateMidnight()
- http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate()

---

Now I'm unsure again, what you want. You want the date in string format now?

```
return simpleDateFormat.format( date);    // from java.util.Date
```

Or with JodaTime:

```
return dateTime.toString( "dd/MM/yy");    // from org.joda.time.DateTime
```

Comment: My date variable gives Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 NZDT 2012 as output. When I do format, I get the right format but how do I convert to Date?

Comment: `date` is a Date. Formatting converts it to String. So you already have the Date parsed correctly! If you really want, you can parse the String back to a Date.. but you already did that once :)

Comment: I understand that using format converts date to String. Before that when I do date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateTime.toLocalDate().toString("dd/MM/yy")); I get Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 NZDT 2012 but I expect it to give me 31/12/12... :(

Comment: Your question's very unclear. I've edited my post to include the other thing you may be attempting to do, but **perhaps you should tell us properly what you're trying to achieve**. What datatype of result do you want & how/where do you intend to use that?

Comment: I want my end result to be Util Date in dd/MM/yy format. I Do not want String. My input is Joda DateTime yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:+GMT. I need to convert JodaDateTime to UtilDate.

Comment: This looks straight forward but I still get result - Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 NZDT 2012. At the end of toDateMidNight() i get 2012-12-31T00:00:00.000+13:00. After .toDate(), it becomes Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 NZDT 2012. But i need answer - 31/12/12

Comment: So you want the Date formatted as dd/MM/yy string? See edit.. but I thought we covered how to do that many hours ago.

Comment: @Sara: As Thomas has said in the comments before, `Date` objects do not have a format by themselves. So, it's impossible to "have a `Date` object in the format `dd/MM/yy`". You specify the format when you convert the `Date` to a `String` for formatting. The `SimpleDateFormat` object knows the format, but not the `Date` object itself.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how you do it

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String string = formatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2012-12-31T13:32:56.483+13:00" ).toLocalDate()
```

## Joda-Time supplanted by java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## ISO 8601

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

The java.time classes use the standard formats by default, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## Date-time objects vs strings

As [the accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18928097/642706) explains, you should not conflate date-time objects with strings that may textually represent their value. A `java.util.Date` **object has no format** as it **has no text**. Ditto for the java.time classes. You can use a java.time object to *parse* a string, or *generate* a string, but the object is distinct and separate from the string.

## `OffsetDateTime`

Parse your input string as a `OffsetDateTime` as it includes an offset-from-UTC though it lacks a time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2012-12-31T13:32:56.483+13:00" );
```

## `LocalDate`

If you want a date-only value, use the `LocalDate` class. Remember that for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. A minute after midnight is a new day in Paris while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec. If you want the date from that same offset of `+13:00`, simply call `toLocalDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = odt.toLocalDate();
```

The Question says you do not want a string, only a date object. So there you go. If you later want a string, call `toString` for a String to be generated in standard ISO 8601 format, `2012-12-31`. For other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 provided date-time classes

```
LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(dateStr,DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```