# Map.lowerKey(Date) not working

Tags: java, treemap

I'm writing an application where I need to read previous lower and next higher date. For that I used reference from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/navigablemap.html#ceilingKey). But Map.lowerKey(Date) every time return same request..(Date) object.

**Sample Code:**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        TreeMap<Date, String> treemap = new TreeMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            treemap.put(c.getTime(), (i + 1) + "");

            if(i == 3)
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);  // number of days to add
            else
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // number of days to add
        }

        c = Calendar.getInstance();

        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        System.out.println("C_Time : "+ c.getTime() + ", L_Time: " + treemap.lowerKey(c.getTime()) + ", G_Time: " + treemap.higherKey(c.getTime()));
```

In response it giving:

> C_Time : Sat May 16 17:39:51 IST 2015, L_Time: Sat May 16 17:39:51 IST
>   2015, G_Time: Sun May 17 17:39:51 IST 2015

Here **higherKey** value is fine but **lowerKey** returning same request object.

Anything I'm missing here ?

Comment: please refer updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your output to this:

```
 System.out.println("C_Time : "+ c.getTime().getTime() 
      + ", L_Time: " + treemap.lowerKey(c.getTime()).getTime() 
      + ", G_Time: " + treemap.higherKey(c.getTime()).getTime());
```

(printing `Date` as millisecond time), you'll receive an output like that:

```
C_Time : 1431779062507, L_Time: 1431779062492, G_Time: 1431865462492
                   ^^^                    ^^^
```

`L_Time`, which was put into the map, is different from `C_Time`, which was created after, in a few milliseconds, and that's why those two dates are treated as different: `L_Time < C_Time`. So your code is working absolutely correctly.

Comment: got it ..#makesense...so as my requirement is there any way to get previous/next date(By Day) for given Date index ?

Comment: @Shubh use `LocalDate` for this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Answer (score 0):

Ahha :) instead to go for LocalDate or JodaTime following trick work:

```
  public Calendar getCleanDate(Calendar targetDate) {
        Calendar newDate = (Calendar) targetDate.clone();
        newDate.setLenient(false);
        newDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        newDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        newDate.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        newDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
        return newDate;
    }
```

Thanks Sasha and Jean to point the issue.

Comment: Using `Date()` with zeroed hours, minutes and seconds is workaround, and it is wrong because of timezone issues (two dates having the same day but defined in different timezones still are different). `LocalDate` class is designed specially to store date information independent on locale and/or timezone.

Comment: Not getting..could u please explain with any example !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050170/java-getting-date-without-time see answers and discussions