# Get current Date without time on CN1

Tags: java, date, codenameone

I have huge Problems getting the Date without time, i want to set the time to 00:00 so i can check date differences.

My steps so far trying:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date now = new Date();
try {
    now = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(now));
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    //
}
```

This code still takes the time, i took this similar code from this question here [How do I get a Date without time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050170/how-do-i-get-a-date-without-time-in-java) answered by Shobbi

I had a better result before but the time was still set to 01:00.
Anyone has a better solution for me?
I need to compare Date from SQLite Database with the Actual day.

Bear in mind that CN1 Datelibs are based on JDK1.3, so im limited using methods

Comment: Do you absolutely need the format `dd-MM-yyyy`?

Comment: The Format is not important in this case, i just need the possibility to check wether the date is in the past or in the future

Comment: I do it by converting Date into Calendar and then calculating difference in DAY_OF_YEAR ( consider leap year for 366 days). Gives you right difference. Calendar class should be available since jdk 1.1

Comment: Next question: do you need to know how far back or forward the date is, or just if it is in the past or future? Your question and comment seem conflicting to me on this.

Comment: Problem here is the Calendar class of CN1, it is limited a bit. i have a Method new Calendar().getSelectedDay(), but this results in "Wed Aug 24 01:00:00 CEST 2016"

Comment: I want to set Status for objects in the past, because of the time difference here, i can not correctly set objects status for todays status, so objects im comparing from today are sorted out to be from yesterday, so the status message is not set correctly.

Comment: Can you not use Calendar class from JDK itself ? You have third party library in your classpath does not mean you have to use it unless you guys have that standard defined for your project.

Comment: I am limited to CN1 Libraries :(

Comment: Can you get day and year out of your dates?

Comment: Nope, if this was the case, it would be easy =)

Comment: Upvote and mark as answer, if my answer is what you needed.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a string? If you use the format `yyyy-MM-dd` a `String.compareTo(otherDateString)` should tell you how the two dates are related (one before, after, or the same day as the other)

For example:

```
String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
//get the other date into a string
boolean isInThePast = (today.compareTo(otherDateString) > 0);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my Date object has no compareTo methods

Comment: @kaya I didn't use a date object.

Comment: yes you are correct, i was wrong =)
Tested your code and its also working (y)

Answer (score 2):

You can compare dates like this without considering the Hour, Minute, Second, and Millisecond:

```
public static int daysBetweenNowAndDate(String date, String format) {
    try {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format); //Change format to your incoming date string format
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.set(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);
        now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Calendar otherDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        otherDate.setTime(dateFormat.parse(date));
        otherDate.set(otherDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), otherDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), otherDate.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);
        otherDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        long divisor = 86400000; // 24 hours (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        long num = now.getTime().getTime() - otherDate.getTime().getTime();
        return (int) ((num + divisor - 1) / divisor);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        return -999999;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
System.out.println(daysBetweenNowAndDate("2016-08-22", "yyyy-MM-dd")); //2
System.out.println(daysBetweenNowAndDate("22-08-2016", "dd-MM-yyyy")); //2
System.out.println(daysBetweenNowAndDate("2016-08-22 22:45", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")); //2
System.out.println(daysBetweenNowAndDate("22-08-2016 22:45:00", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")); //2
System.out.println(daysBetweenNowAndDate("2016-08-22 22:45", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")); //-999999 because the format and the date don't correspond
```

Comment: Thank you mate, the first FOUR lines should help me in this case(y)

Comment: You're welcome, upvote and mark as answer if it helps.

Comment: Hey Mate, i copied your Code but i get syntax errors :\

Comment: "The method set(int, int) in the type Calendar is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, int, int, int)" in Line 5. But your code directed me already to the right direction(y). i think you wanted to set each value on its own instead of a single method call in this case?

Comment: I'm curious, what version of Java are you using and on what IDE?

Comment: Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) on JDK8_102, CN1 project stuff set all to 1.8

Comment: yeah, maybe the reason why i was not able to get the correct syntax set, because i had all the newer/better/easier syntaxes on Google and Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer after the several suggestions, thanks to you folks

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
now.getTime();
```

The important thing here is to take the import `java.util.Calendar` instead of the `com.codename1.ui.Calendar`.

Also a bit of my mistake, in this case, I used the Calendar and got confused by using wrong import :\

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Joda time library which can fix your problem

Comment: Joda time library is not supported in Codename one

Comment: oh, yeah! I don't remember such limit of CN1, thx for remind it. But Joda time is useful in such way!