# Android DatePicker values shows the wrong value

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am trying to get the selected date from the datepicker but I could not get the correct value. My code is given below.

```
View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.set_date_layout, null);

    dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(RemainderActivity.this);
    dialog.title(R.string.set_date);

    datePicker = (DatePicker) mView.findViewById(R.id.datePickerRemainder);


    dialog.customView(mView, true);
    dialog.positiveText(R.string.confirm_date);
    dialog.negativeText(android.R.string.cancel);
    dialog.cancelable(false);
    dialog.onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Log.d("YEAR", datePicker.getYear()+""); //Shows correct year as 2017
            Date date = new Date(datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), (datePicker.getMonth() + 1),datePicker.getYear()); // Wrong date as 09-04-1907
            String dateString = df.format(date);
            txt_remainder_date_add.setText(dateString);
        }
    });
    dialog.build();
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: what date you trying to select and what u getting include both!

Comment: I am trying to select 02-Sep-2017 it shows 08-Aug-1908.. If I select 01-Sep-2017 it shows 04-Sep-1907

Comment: because in date picker month starts from 0 not from 1, see my code below and try to use it, Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void datepicker() {
    // Get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    date_time = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
txt_remainder_date_add.setText(date_time);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

where my DialogTheme defined in style :

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

call this method where ever you want

Comment: yes @SharaafNazeer it will work completely fine upto api15 to 25

Comment: The out put I am getting here is 2-9-2017.. How can I make it as 02-09-2017?.

Comment: I could not format it.. I'm getting following error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String


This is my code segment 

global_date = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;

                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        String dateString = df.format(global_date);
                        txt_remainder_date_add.setText(dateString);

Comment: Please remove - from string then try

Answer (score 0):

**According to this** [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html)

you have used deprecated code in below line :

```
Date date = new Date(datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), (datePicker.getMonth() + 1),datePicker.getYear());
```

Instead of using **Date** class try **Calendar** class object like this...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

you can refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050170/how-do-i-get-a-date-without-time-in-java) for example...