# Removing square braces from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove square brackets for this one. I tried it but it gives same output.

```
String datetime = [Thu Sep 14 17:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017];
datetime=datetime.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @Batty You can see the code is in the question.

Comment: your string assignment is wrong. Do it like `String datetime = "[Thu Sep 14 17:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017]";` And you are good to go. Your code works.

Comment: Use `System.out.println(datetime);` to verify.

Comment: @ batty that datetime comes from backend like what i wrote in the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you're already setting the datetime String on your own, why don't you just set it without square brackets?
`String datetime = "Thu Sep 14 17:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017";`

And you're supposed to have a compiler error because your String datetime is not valid, because it has no double quotes.

On the other hand if you receive a data for datetime String from Java class `Date` then you can change the format of the data you're receiving with `SimpleDateFormat`.

If you do not know how to use SimpleDateFormat, check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050170/how-do-i-get-a-date-without-time-in-java)

Here's some brief example of it and you can check full tutorial [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/):

```
public class GetCurrentDateTime {

private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
private static final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(dtf.format(now));

    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyy/MM/dd").format(localDate));

}
```

}

Comment: This definitely isn't your code...

Comment: It's not, so what? I could wrote it by myself and it would pretty similar and the point is the same, I just wanted to give fast and clear answer.

Comment: The whole point was to link/accredit any external reference, and you seem to have done that based on my comment, which is what I wanted. I rest my case. No need to get defensive.

Answer (score -1):

Don't replace brackets with nothing, match inside of brackets with regex, then replace whole string with inside part.

Like this

```
String datetime = "[Thu Sep 14 17:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017]";
datetime=datetime.replaceAll("\\[(.*)\\]", "$1");
System.out.println( datetime); // output is: Thu Sep 14 17:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017
```