# Is there a better way to zero out Calendar date?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I'm looking to see if there is a better way in obtaining the same result as the following code:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

I'm using this to be able to compare the difference in days between two dates. I am currently coding for target API 24 and am not interested in using Joda Time for such a simple task.

I've come up with the following function, but would love to hear if there is a simpler, perhaps built in, method for either zeroing out the date or an entire different method for getting the amount of days between two dates.

```
private long getFlatDateInMillis() {
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    currentDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    currentDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    currentDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    currentDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return currentDate.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

That way, I could quickly use:

```
Calendar date = getFlatDateInMillis();
```

I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything that is simpler, already pre-defined.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need it. If it works. in this way the question is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for replying.

"I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything that is simpler, already pre-defined."

Comment: you can't ask such questions on SO because you didn't tell what do you think  is simpler, already pre-defined

Comment: Possible this discussion will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050170/how-do-i-get-a-date-without-time-in-java

Comment: `currentDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());` can be removed. Otherwise, this could be done cleaner with Joda Time or [ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). If you don't want to use those, then this is fine.

Comment: Thank you @Shobhit

Comment: So, I only need to use `currentDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());` when setting a date _back_ to the current time, correct?

Comment: Or to set a calendar date to midnight 
 of that day currentDate.setTimeInMillis((currentDate.getTimeInMillis()/86400000)*86400000)

Comment: @Andy that only works if the timezone is UTC.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(                    // Calculate elapsed time between a pair of `LocalDate` date-only objects. Returns a total number of elapsed days.
    ( (GregorianCalendar) myJavaUtilCal )   // Cast your legacy `java.util.Calendar` object to the subclass `java.util.GregorianCalendar`, also legacy. 
        .toZonedDateTime()                  // Convert from legacy `GregorianCalendar` to modern `ZonedDateTime` class.
        .toLocalDate()  ,                   // Extract the date-only value, a `LocalDate`, lacking time-of-day and lacking time zone.
    otherLocalDate                          // Compare to some other `LocalDate` object.
)                                           // Returns a `long` number of days. Uses Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.
```

## Details

The [Answer by Kareem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49354986/642706) is correct. Some more thoughts here.

> Is there a better way to zero out Calendar date?

**Yes, there is a better way: don’t.**

- Trying to clear out the time-of-day on a date+time types is the wrong approach; use a date-only type instead ([`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)).
- And don’t use the troublesome old legacy classes such as `Calendar`, `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` as they are now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

> the difference in days between two dates

First convert your legacy `Calendar` object to the modern `ZonedDateTime` class. To convert, call new methods added to the old classes.

```
GregorianCalendar myGregCal = (GregorianCalendar) myJavaUtilCal ; // Cast from superclass to subclass. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ; // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
```

Extract the date-only value.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;  // Extract date-only object from date-time object.
```

Calculate elapsed time in days

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( ld , otherLd ) ;
```

Or represent the elapsed time as a [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Period.html).

```
Period p = Period.between( ld , otherLd ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I'm choosing to mark this as the answer only because of the added context/helpful code example. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is with the `java.time.LocalDate` class.  It stores only the date, not the time, and it has a `now()` static method, which returns the current day.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
```

If you're looking at Android, this was added at API level 26, but there are other ways of using the "new style" date classes with Android, such as the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library.

Comment: I like this answer. Will have to heavily consider this as it is future maintainable. Thank you very much.

Comment: For use on pre-26 Android, see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: I wanted to use java.time really badly (so much easier to use), but had no idea of ThreeTen backport. Thank you to the both of you.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Thanks to Basil and Kareem, I've updated to the following code (so, so much easier):

Added to gradle.build:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.5'
```

Then, in my activity, etc,

```
AndroidThreeTen.init(this);

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate anotherDay = LocalDate.of(2019, 3, 25);
long dayDifference = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, anotherDay); //dayDifference = 365
```

One thing of note is that Calendar references months starting at 0 index, whereas LocalDate references months starting at 1 index.