# How do I create the java date object without time stamp

Tags: java, date, timezone, simpledateformat

I want to create a Date object without a TimeZone (eg : `2007-06-21`). Is this possible?

When I use the following method it prints like `Thu Jun 21 00:00:00 GMT 2007`

```
SimpleDateFormat  sdf       = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

TimeZone          timeZone  = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
timeZone.setDefault(timeZone);
sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);

Date              pickUpDate = sdf.parse("2007-06-21");
System.out.println(pickUpDate);
```

Comment: A date does not have a format.

Comment: exact duplicate [java program to get the current date without timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806360/java-program-to-get-the-current-date-without-timestamp), additional duplicate candidates are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050170/java-getting-date-without-time?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java?rq=1

Comment: @DharshanSithamparam Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to *format* a date, you need to use `DateFormat` or something similar. A `Date` is *just* an instant in time - the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. It doesn't have any idea of time zone, calendar system or format. The `toString()` method always uses the system local time zone, and always formats it in a default way. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--):

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

So it's behaving exactly as documented.

You've already got a `DateFormat` with the right format, so you just need to call `format` on it:

```
System.out.println("pickUpDate" + sdf.format(pickUpDate));
```

Of course it doesn't make much sense in your sample, given that you've only just parsed it - but presumably you'd normally be passing the date around first.

Note that if this is for interaction with a database, it would be better not to pass it as a string at all. Keep the value in a "native" representation for as much of the time as possible, and use something like `PreparedStatement.setDate` to pass it to the database.

As an aside, if you can *possibly* change to use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) or the new date/time API in Java 8 (`java.time.*`) you'll have a much smoother time of it with anything date/time-related. The `Date`/`Calendar` API is truly dreadful.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `toString()` of the `java.util.Date`

```
    public String toString() {

        // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
        BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
        int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
        if (index == gcal.SUNDAY) {
            index = 8;
        }

        convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');            // EEE
        convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss

        TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
        if (zi != null) {
            sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), zi.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
        } else {
            sb.append("GMT");
        }

        sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

So, if you will pass a Date and try to print it this will be printed out all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
Date date = new Date();     
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date));
```

Date : `Fri Apr 29 04:53:16 GMT 2016`

Sample Output : `2016-04-29`

Imports required :

```
import java.util.Date; //for new Date()
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; // for the format change
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("pickUpDate " + sdf.format(pickUpDate));
```

You can use the above code to get formatted `Date` as `String`

Answer (score 0):

`Date` isn't a date. It's a timestamp. That's some impressive API design, isn't it?

The type you need is now [java.time.LocalDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), added in Java 8.

If you can't use Java 8, you can use [ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a backport for Java 7.

Comment: Much as I agree that LocalDate would be preferrable, it's a little too early to assume everyone can use Java 8.

Comment: Updated the answer to mention the Java 7 backport.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date pickUpDate =sdf.parse("2007-06-21");
System.out.println("pickUpDate "+sdf.format(pickUpDate));
```

Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String your_format_date=sdf.format(pickUpDate);
 System.out.println("pick Up Date " + your_format_date);
```